# Use jQuery plugins that change DOM in React

Tags: jquery, dom, reactjs

I am using a plugin called [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to convert a list of divs into a carousel. Now I want to use the function call `$('.slider').slick('slickRemove',index);` to remove a selected div from the carousel. This will change the original DOM structure and cause `Uncaught Invariant Violation` in React. So what is the best way to use jQuery plugins which change the original DOM in React?

```
var ImageItem = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
        <div className="center-inline imageItem">
            // onClick deleted this div
            <button className="circular red extra-mini ui icon button top-right"
                    onClick={this.props.onclick.bind(null, this.props.url)}>
                <i className="large remove icon"></i>
            </button>
            <img className="center-block" src={this.props.url} />
        </div>
        );
    },
});

var ImageSlider = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            urls: ["/static/img/oned.jpg", "/static/img/oned2.jpg", "/static/img/oned3.jpg"],
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        //call slick plugin
        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.imgSlider)).slick({
            infinite: false,
            mobileFirst: true,
            lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        });
    },
    deleteImg: function(url){
        var index = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<this.state.urls.length;i++){
            if(this.state.urls[i] == url){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // update urls, delete the selected url
        newUrls = this.state.urls
        newUrls.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({
            urls: newUrls,
        },function(){
            // delete the selected div
            $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.imgSlider)).slick('slickRemove', index);
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        items = [];
        this.state.urls.forEach(function(u){
            items.push(<ImageItem url={u} key={u} onclick={this.deleteImg} />)
        }.bind(this));

        return (
            <div>
                <div ref="imgSlider" className="imageSlider">
                {items}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: what about https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

Comment: react-slick does not support deleting div.

Comment: It absolutely does. If you have your images in an array saved in state, then remove an item from that array, react-slick will automatically update with the new items. `<Slider {...settings}>{ this.state.images }</Slider>`

Comment: In React applications you rarely fuss with the DOM like deleting or adding divs. you just modify state with `this.setState` and React  handles the rest.

Comment: I tried this before. But it does not work. It seems that slick does not take care of the content once it is initialized. Can you please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codecancer/fzd2twwv/) ?

Comment: It works fine, you just have syntax errors.. here: https://jsfiddle.net/y8r67hvL/6/

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you azium! But I still want to know what is the best way to use jQuery plugins which modify DOMs in react. What if the plugin unfortunately does not have a react version like react-slick?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure... I would probably just not use React.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite tricky to do this, basically you have to make react ignore those elements. There is a nice tutorial here, but i would not recommend that if you see another way: https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md